# Getting relative frequency of each character in a string in java

Tags: java, string, frequency

I wanted to get the average of each unique character in a string. I have an example here as it would be easier to illustrate it.

String:

```
The big brown fox
```

Average of each character including spaces:

```
T = 1/17 = .058
h = 1/17 = .058
e = 1/17 = .058
' '= 3/17 = .176
b = 2/17 = .117
i = 1/17 = .058
g = 1/17 = .058
r = 1/17 = .058
o = 2/17 = .117
w = 1/17 = .058
n = 1/17 = .058
f = 1/17 = .058
x = 1/17 = .058
```

So far all my attempts have failed, think my brain is not working at the moment. How do I code this? Any help or input will be greatly appreciated.

I have this code as a solution. It just came to me when I was copy pasting my code here in stack. I hope this is not a re-post because I just answered the same thing a few minutes ago but it didn't show up.

```
 Map<String, Integer> storeCharCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        String a = "The big brown fox";


        for (int x=0; x<a.length(); x++){
            char getChar = a.charAt(x);
            String convGetChar = Character.toString(getChar);

            Integer countChar = storeCharCount.get(convGetChar);
            storeCharCount.put(convGetChar, (countChar==null?countChar=1:countChar+1));

        }
        System.out.println("Map: "+ storeCharCount);
        double RelFrequency = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> getValue: storeCharCount.entrySet()){

            RelFrequency = (double)(getValue.getValue())/(a.length());
            System.out.println("Character "+getValue.getKey() +"  Relative Frequency: "+RelFrequency);

        }
```

Here is the output

```
Map: {f=1, g=1,  =3, e=1, b=2, n=1, o=2, h=1, i=1, w=1, T=1, r=1, x=1}
Character f  Relative Frequency: 0.058823529411764705
Character g  Relative Frequency: 0.058823529411764705
Character    Relative Frequency: 0.17647058823529413
Character e  Relative Frequency: 0.058823529411764705
Character b  Relative Frequency: 0.11764705882352941
Character n  Relative Frequency: 0.058823529411764705
Character o  Relative Frequency: 0.11764705882352941
Character h  Relative Frequency: 0.058823529411764705
Character i  Relative Frequency: 0.058823529411764705
Character w  Relative Frequency: 0.058823529411764705
Character T  Relative Frequency: 0.058823529411764705
Character r  Relative Frequency: 0.058823529411764705
Character x  Relative Frequency: 0.058823529411764705
```

Comment: The most straight forward solution would be a java.util.HashMap<Character, Integer>

Comment: How about you show us what you've done, then we can work from there? I'm sure we could all learn from it.

Comment: I tried using the variation of using map.put(character, charCount=null?charCount=0:charCount+1) but this code can gives me the sum of each character and I have hard time getting the value part of this map "map(Key, Value)".

Comment: it should be charCount = map.get(character); map.put(character,charCount=null?0:charCount+1). Note the charCount variable is local and inside the loop ( I assume you have a loop to pick each char in the word). do a type cast to number when required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my suggestion. Start by iterating over every character in the String, update freq if found else add 1. Then iterate again to print result :

```
        String s = "The big brown fox";
    Map<Character, Float> m = new TreeMap<Character, Float>();
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (m.containsKey(c))
            m.put(c, m.get(c) + 1);
        else
            m.put(c, 1f);
    }

    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        float freq = m.get(c) / s.length();
        System.out.println(c + " " + freq);
    }
```

Comment: Hi I like your code but I think its the same output as to what I have. I'll use this variation soon. thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there any specific reason for choosing TreeMap over other Map implementations in this case?

Comment: If you ask me it helps in my case because its easy to sort out the values obtain inside treemap. Other than that I don't know.

Comment: @Abhilash: Any map is ok, I had a different printout part first where all characters were printed in alphabetical order, and didn't change map type afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that this is the best way, but you can count each letter [a-z][A-Z] and remove every `" "` and then calculate = count of letter/all letters.

Comment: I can't remove the space because its part of unique characters. Also I don't think that counting from a-z - A-Z would is not that efficient as I need to do this at least 80M Strings with each string having a minimum of 0-700 characters. But thank you for replying.

Comment: @dimas: 80M string is not a big one actually, since you can iterate all of the chars in less than a second. If you need exact answers, you need to iterate all of the chars, otherwise, how can you count the frequency? Another way, if approximate results is acceptable for you, is random sampling of the chars.

Comment: Hi Mohsen the data am trying to manipulate is already sampled the original number of Strings is 1.7B for approximately 14 hrs of data gathering. I still need 4 more days each with 14 hrs. thank your thoughts on it though.